# Is the union of NP Complete language and a finite language (in P) NP Complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, closure-properties

Let there be a language $A$ which is NP complete and language $B$ which is a finite language, is the union of $A \cup B$ NP complete language?

Comment: As a general thumb rule, adding and/or removing a finite number of words from a language in any "well-known" class, creates a new language in the same class. (Of course, this is not true for _all_ classes of problems, e.g. a class containing only one problem. However, if a class is so "fragile" to be affected by finite modifications, then the class is not very interesting and hardly becomes a "well-known" one)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes, and this is a special case of the following statement:

Let $X$, $Y$ be non-trivial languages (ie either empty nor everything) such that the symmetric difference $(X \setminus Y) \cup (Y \setminus X)$ is finite. Then $X \leq Y$ (linear time, constant space manyone reduction).

The reduction just tests whether the input is any of the finitely many values in $(X \setminus Y) \cup (Y \setminus X)$ and proceeds in a hard-coded way there. This takes constant time+space. Otherwise, it copies the input, since $X$ and $Y$ will agree there.

How to use this: For NP-hardness of $A \cup B$, set $X := A$ and $Y := A \cup B$. For NP-membership of $A \cup B$, set $X := A \cup B$ and $Y := A$. Note that the symmetric difference of $A$ and $A \cup B$ is included in $B$, hence if $B$ is finite, so is the symmetric difference.

Comment: I think the symmetric difference of the two language doesn't have to be finite (since one language is NPC doesn't have to be finite) Let's say one language is vertex-cover and the other language is $B = \{a\}$ then the symmetric difference is $A \cup B$ which is not finite

Comment: If $B$ is finite, then the symmetric difference of $A$ and $A \cup B$ is finite (since it is a subset of $B$).

Comment: I think what is confusing in this answer is the naming of the languages w.r.t. the question. OP's NP-complete $A$ is also named $A$ in this answer, but Arno's $B$ is actually $A \cup B$ from the question, not the sole finite $B$!
Also one may add a short argument why $A \cup B$ actually is in NP.

Comment: @PHPNick Point taken. I've renamed stuff.

Comment: A bit old question, but isn't the symmetric difference is $\left(X\backslash Y\right)\cup\left(Y\backslash X\right)$? Also does it mean that $X\leq Y$ **and** $Y\leq X$? Is it also polynominal?

Comment: @vesii Thanks for alerting me to the typo which has persisted for so long! Since you can freely interchange $X$ and $Y$ in the argument, also $Y \leq X$ holds. This works for essentially any reasonable reducibility notion, see the details of the argument.